# Apple Push Notification Provisioning For Production

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, push, production

I'm really tired today for creation of apple push service provision. I've created development certificate and provisioning profile which was worked fine for my app. Now when i want to create production provision i don't get my created Apple Push Notification certificate for selection.Please anybody help me.I don't get my desired created certificate here [apple screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL9x4.png)

Comment: Hi @Trena , 
This video may help you please look at it once 
1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwQtzNoyjMs
2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xh2nnjttOwo

Comment: Can you please add a screen shot to show what you want to do.

Comment: Hi @ Meheta, I have already created push config for dev and it work's fine. But for production when i try to create my provision for production i don't get my created production certificate for selection.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fastlane](http://fastlane.tools) to generate push certificates easily and without hassle. Here is a [blog post](https://handcraftedios.com/2017/01/29/how-to-issue-apple-push-notifications-certificates-without-hassle/) covering whole process